# Why is my json code gives Instance of Post

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from internet. And this is the json string:

```
{"channel":{"id":1090161,"name":"İscaklik","description":"İscakliği okeyrum da.","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0","field1":"nem","field2":"iscaklik","created_at":"2020-06-27T11:56:47Z","updated_at":"2020-06-27T11:56:47Z","last_entry_id":1},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2020-06-27T12:02:32Z","entry_id":1,"field1":"5"}]}
```

I want to get the "field1" in "feeds".
And my code is like that:

```
class _DataState extends State<Data> {
  Future<String> AlbumState;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    oku();
  }

  var a;

  Future<List<Post>> oku() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1090161/fields/1.json?api_key=JD9JYHAT2YHOI5Q3&results=1');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return (responseJson['feeds'] as List)
          .map((p) => Post.fromJson(p))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('La bulamadık la böyle bi şey yoh la');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
            future: oku(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Post {
  final String field1;

  Post({this.field1});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Post(
      field1: json['entry_id'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result:
[image: It gives me this]

I want to see the 5.(Which is the field1 of feeds)
Why I am seeing this?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you trying to use the entire object like the String in the Text widget. Try to call the attribute `field1` you have in the Post class.

```
return Text(snapshot.data[0].field1);
```

Comment: It gives this error when I write that: The getter 'field1' isn't defined for the type 'List<Feed>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'field1', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named

Comment: I edited the answer, try to add an index to data like the code above. But after that you need create another Post class to map the attributtes you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

**Just Copy And Paste this model class and the simple use**

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
       ModelChannel channel = ModelChannel.fromJson(responseJson);
      
      return  channel.feeds;
    } else {
      throw Exception('La bulamadık la böyle bi şey yoh la');
    }
```

**Here is your JSON model**

```
class ModelChannel {
        Channel channel;
        List<Feed> feeds;
    
        ModelChannel({this.channel, this.feeds});
    
        factory ModelChannel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return ModelChannel(
                channel: json['channel'] != null ? Channel.fromJson(json['channel']) : null, 
                feeds: json['feeds'] != null ? (json['feeds'] as List).map((i) => Feed.fromJson(i)).toList() : null, 
            );
        }
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
            final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
            if (this.channel != null) {
                data['channel'] = this.channel.toJson();
            }
            if (this.feeds != null) {
                data['feeds'] = this.feeds.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
    
    class Feed {
        String created_at;
        int entry_id;
        String field1;
    
        Feed({this.created_at, this.entry_id, this.field1});
    
        factory Feed.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return Feed(
                created_at: json['created_at'], 
                entry_id: json['entry_id'], 
                field1: json['field1'], 
            );
        }
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
            final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
            data['created_at'] = this.created_at;
            data['entry_id'] = this.entry_id;
            data['field1'] = this.field1;
            return data;
        }
    }
    
    class Channel {
        String created_at;
        String description;
        String field1;
        String field2;
        int id;
        int last_entry_id;
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        String name;
        String updated_at;
    
        Channel({this.created_at, this.description, this.field1, this.field2, this.id, this.last_entry_id, this.latitude, this.longitude, this.name, this.updated_at});
    
        factory Channel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return Channel(
                created_at: json['created_at'], 
                description: json['description'], 
                field1: json['field1'], 
                field2: json['field2'], 
                id: json['id'], 
                last_entry_id: json['last_entry_id'], 
                latitude: json['latitude'], 
                longitude: json['longitude'], 
                name: json['name'], 
                updated_at: json['updated_at'], 
            );
        }
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
            final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
            data['created_at'] = this.created_at;
            data['description'] = this.description;
            data['field1'] = this.field1;
            data['field2'] = this.field2;
            data['id'] = this.id;
            data['last_entry_id'] = this.last_entry_id;
            data['latitude'] = this.latitude;
            data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
            data['name'] = this.name;
            data['updated_at'] = this.updated_at;
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for your helps but it still gives the same result.

Comment: I added your script and this line Text(snapshot.data[0].field1); and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this code, You should call the attribute `data.feeds[0].field1`-

```
function ItemListCtrl($scope, $http) {


$http.get("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1090161/fields/1.json?api_key=JD9JYHAT2YHOI5Q3&results=1", {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data.feeds[0].field1)
    $scope.data = angular.fromJson(data.feeds[0].field1);
  });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm3oadp6/10/)

Comment: Sorry but is this java script